# Slow iteration through a JSONArray in GWT

Tags: java, performance, json, gwt

I'm using GWT to build an application, and I'm facing serious speed issues with something that I thought would be pretty fast. I have a JSONObject with data in the following structure (but that is much larger):

```
{"nodeData" : [ 
                { "name":"one", "attributes":["uno","dos"]}, 
                {"name":"two", "attributes":["tres"]}
              ]
}
```

I am trying to iterate through the JSON object to store all the attributes into an arraylist which every node object has, with attribute sizes ranging from 4 to 800.

```
JSONObject JSONnode = nodeData.get(i).isObject();
Node node = new Node(JSONnode.get("name").toString();
JSONArray attributeArray = JSONnode.get("Attributes").isArray();
int attributeSize = attributeArray.size();


for(int j = 0; k < attributeSize; j++){
    node.attributeArrayList.add(attributeArray.get(j).toString();
}
```

The for loop I'm executing is taking about a minute, which seems too long, and I'm not sure how to improve it. The minute is in development mode, but I don't know if it would be any faster when I compile it.

Comment: The way you are parsing the JSON structure is fine. A minute sounds a little bit much for around 800 records. However I can guarantee that performance is fine in production mode (you should actually try it). For testing purposes you could remove the node.attributeArrayList.add() call and see if it affects performance. BTW which browser are you using in development mode?

Comment: The reason I'm not using production mode is because I'm getting a 404 error on an async call. Since I'm not getting a 404 on development mode, I've just stayed with using it. My search for answers suggested it might be a SOP problem, so I've kind of pushed fixing it aside.

Comment: A 404 has nothing to do with SOP (because 404 means the server has been reached). It might however very well be that you're using an absolute path, which works in dev mode because the webapp is deployed at the ROOT of the server, but not in prod mode where you deployed the webapp with a non-empty "context path". Most likely the fix is to concatenate your path to `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()` so it's "relative" to your host page, wherever it is deployed.

Comment: I initially had it as GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + servletName so I changed it to getHostPageBaseURL which gave me a 404 for development too.

Comment: The 404 happens when I have it hosted on a localhost. When opening the html file from my project directory, I get a (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI): Access to restricted URI denied code: 1012... error
Sorry for diverting the topic

Comment: I suggest you open a new question with the details on the production mode errors.

Comment: I had observed similar problems in performance in Dev mode, seems iterating through a JSONArray and JSONObject takes about half a minute for six hundred records. Running the same application in production mode worked just fine. 

I would be interested to see if you had figured out why it runs so slow in Dev..

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using overlays?

[GWT Coding Basics - JavaScript Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html)

You can create overlay types pretty easily:-

```
// An overlay type
class Customer extends JavaScriptObject {

  // Overlay types always have protected, zero-arg ctors
  protected Customer() { }

  // Typically, methods on overlay types are JSNI
  public final native String getFirstName() /*-{ return this.FirstName; }-*/;
  public final native String getLastName()  /*-{ return this.LastName;  }-*/;

  // Note, though, that methods aren't required to be JSNI
  public final String getFullName() {
    return getFirstName() + " " + getLastName();
  }
}
```

Very easy to use and I think would be much faster than using JSONObject objects.

Answer (score 0):

How do you use GWT ? Inside an IDE ?
In my experience, having too many breakpoints slows down the execution flow, may be you could check that ?
Particularly when I see that in production it seems fine...

Answer (score 0):

If everything else fails, you can always write that in native Javascript and call it via JSNI.